# WebService default uri java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'uri' must not be empty

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am consuming a Soap WebService using spring WebServiceTemplate & below is the bean creation and my bean class but dont know why i am unable to get the value of Default Uri.
Can someone please help with this thing.

ServiceContext.java

```
        @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.canaldigital.tsi.schema.psd.psd_managecustomer.v2");        
        return marshaller;
    }


    @Bean
    public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory factory=new SaajSoapMessageFactory();

    factory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);
        return factory;
    }    

     @Bean
    public ManageService voucherService(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller,SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory) {
         ManageService service = new ManageService();

        service.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:7001/CustomerService?WSDL");
        service.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        service.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        service.setMessageFactory(messageFactory);
        return service;
    }
```

ManageService.java

```
    public class ManageService extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    try{

    System.out.println("Finalyy calllingggg service: "+getWebServiceTemplate());    
    System.out.println("WebService template URI is: ---- "+getWebServiceTemplate().getDefaultUri());


    JAXBElement<GetCustomerInfoRequestType> mustangRequst=new createGetCustomerInfoRequest(customer);


     (JAXBElement<GetCustomerInfoResponseType>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(mustangRequst);


    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

         }

    }
```

Comment: You are pointing to the WSDL, not to the service. Your uri should look like this `service.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:7001/CustomerService);`

Comment: I have checked with that as well. That didn't worked. Still same error.

Comment: Please, include the full trace of the error

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any pointers on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have @Service annotation on the service.

Answer (score 0):

you should use @Autowired when you call your client that extends WebServiceGatewaySupport